# How to attach file to an email using Java?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

Hello guys I created a simple form in which I put all the email information.
This Code works perfectly but I want to attach a file with the message.
What can I do to add to this code so I can attach my file ?
This is the code:

```
public class UserMailDispatcher extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private MailSenderBean mailSender;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException, MessagingException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");


        String toEmail = request.getParameter("email");
        String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
        String message = request.getParameter("message");

        String fromEmail = "example.gmtt@gmail.com";
        String username = "example.gmtt";
        String password = "example";


        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {


            mailSender.sendEmail(fromEmail, username, password, toEmail, subject, message);
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
public class MailSenderBean {

    public void sendEmail(String fromEmail, String username, String password, String toEmail, String subject, String message) throws MessagingException {

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");


        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);

        Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
        mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
        mailMessage.setContent(message, "text/html");
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);

        transport.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this updated function:

```
@Stateless
public class MailSenderBean {

public void sendEmail(String fromEmail, String username, String password, String toEmail, String subject, String message) throws MessagingException{

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");


    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);

    Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
    mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
    mailMessage.setContent(message, "text/html");       
    mailMessage.setSubject(subject);

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);

    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText("File attached:");
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    DataSource source = new FileDataSource("location\of\file");
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    mailMessage.setContent(multipart);

    transport.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());


}
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for replying but there's an error in the line "message.setContent(multipart); " - Cannot find method setContent(Multipart)

Comment: It should be mailMessage.setContent(multipart); I've updated the answer.

Comment: it's done but there's some  exceptions here's a link
https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t35.0-12/12279661_544664062377682_1523155407_o.jpg?oh=ecb6a4820e0a994fb1002bba1b5b8911&oe=56E0B75C

Comment: It is on a container side, since he cannot find MailSenderBean. It is not connected with sending mails.

Comment: Post another question on stack overflow, since, this is not connected with sending attachments. Post your code and .xml files in a new question.